# NUnit Addins with Resharper 5

Tags: nunit, resharper

The latest Resharper (v5) version is based on native NUnit code and allows NUnit addins.

I have a NUnit addin that works fine in NUnit GUI but I can not make it work with Resharper. Based on R# indication I have put my addins library in `%ResharperPath%\Bin\addins` but I doesn't work, my tests are marked as `Ignored`.

**Question:** How to use NUnit addins with ReSharper?

Comment: can suggest only one more place to ask/search - jetbrains devnet http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_community

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, ReSharper's test runner doesn't support NUnit add-ins. It's been [requested](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-205480), but hasn't been added, not even to the forthcoming ReSharper 6. (Feel free to vote for the feature request to let them know there's interest -- I just did.)

We use an NUnit add-in for some of our tests, and those tests don't show up in ReSharper at all -- no gutter icons, nothing in the Unit Tests window, nothing. Our only option is, when we want to run those tests, to fire up the NUnit GUI. It's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Now ReSharper supports NUnit addins. Try this link:
http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2013/06/nunit-addins-that-works-with-resharper/

Also you need to change default settings in resharper:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/80G3C.png

Options -> Tools -> Unit Testing -> NUnit

Load NUnit Addins -> Always

and copy dll with Addin to C:\Users...\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs12\addins

Also your dll with tests (not with addin) must not contain NUnit.AddinsDependencies package